# Home structured cabling - which cables?

Tags: video, home-networking, voip, cabling

I've recently purchased a 25U rack with some networking for my home. I'm about to order some Cat6, but I wanted to ask a few questions:

I noticed that some people have video cabling in their homes. Is there a reason to worry about this type of cabling if your security cameras are IP?

I'd also like to put in some type of communication system between me and my children. I'm planning on putting in a 3CX 14 Free server, could I install a couple of intercomm type speakers with this system?

Comment: 3CX is a SIP based communication server, it will support most SIP endpoints, including phones, speakers, intercom stations, video conference systems, paging interfaces, etc. There are literally hundreds of devices which could probably be used for this project.

Comment: And on the coax piece, most likely not... If your cameras are IP, then why would you need coax cable, at least for them. I still recommend RG6 and 2 CAT-5e/6 installed per outlet in standard rooms, never more than 8-12 feet apart.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your insight, this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

3CX is only IP so nothing but Ethernet cabling would be of much use. Even if you wanted to run an analog phone somewhere, you could still do that via Ethernet cabling and an FXO converter.

I use 3CX as an intercom through a softphone on a PC. I even use Cat5e to run my loud speakers. PC 3.5mm jack to mini amp to cat5E to loudspeakers =)

Video cabling would be for older analog security cameras. If you had an analog system though you could still use ethernet cables with baluns at the end to run those.

I've been surprised at how many scenarios cheap Ethernet cabling has been able to work for me.